# Exclude all 0s in foreach count

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I want to update all my custom_field by giving specific number to each of my posts. Problem : I don't want to add numbers with 0 inside.

```
$i = 1; // Start from 1

if ($ajax_query->have_posts()) : 
    while ($ajax_query->have_posts()) : 
        $ajax_query->the_post(); 

        update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'the_custom_field', $i++ ); 
        // $i++ will be the specific number for each my post.

    endwhile;
endif;
```

Now, my post 1 has the_custom_field 1, my post 2 has the_custom_field 2.... my post 10 has the_custom_field 10

But it should be this way :

- the_custom_field of post1 should be 1
- the_custom_field of post2 should be 2
- the_custom_field of post3 should be 3
- ...
- the_custom_field of post10 should be 11
- the_custom_field of post11 should be 12
  etc

Comment: How it possible man ?

Comment: I guess post 11 will be number 12.

Comment: Yes post 11 will be 12 etc.

Comment: So check if the post id contains a `0` character, and if so add one more to $i? _“It should postpone the others”_ - “postpone” how? Do you simply mean you want to not update posts 10, 20, … at all?

Comment: I edited the question. Postpone was maybe not the good word.

Comment: `if ( strpos( (string)get_the_ID(), '0' ) !== false )` …

Comment: Use a while loop.

Comment: @04FS I don't want to check the post ID. All posts have to be updated with a number. I just don't want to add a number with a 0 inside. If $i++ has a zero, then don't update this specific number but add the next number which doesn't have a 0

Comment: Convert the ID to base 9 using [`base_convert($id, 10, 9)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) then add 1 to every character in the resulting string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php


if ($ajax_query->have_posts()) : 
    while ($ajax_query->have_posts()) : 
        $ajax_query->the_post(); 

        update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'the_custom_field', $i++); 
        while (strpos(strval($i),'0') !== false):
            $i++;
        endwhile;

    endwhile;
endif;
```

Well, once we assign the ID, we run a while loop afterwards till the time we get a value which doesn't contain the `0`.

Comment: The logic is what i want, but it's not working, it keeps loading

Comment: @Youstart Naturally, because it's a brute force approach. Looks like you are updating a lot of rows, but can you let me know as to why such a requirement?

Comment: I am not sure because I have like 60 posts and if i update my posts (with regular $i), it takes less than a sec. I could add manually my custom_post_field but was trying to find a quicker way for the future.

Comment: @Youstart I have made the change in my code. It should work fine now.

Comment: @Youstart Happy to help :). But note that this could get slow on large number of rows due to the computation itself and also because of the DB query fired each time in the loop.

Comment: Yes sure, I will need to do it once in a while and not everyday. thanks